# How do I grant all privileges for a database to a role in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to grant all privileges for a database to a role in snowflake

This includes all ability to read, create, update and delete schemas, stages, storage integrations, tables and so on.

Also should include any future objects created in the database.

```
    grant all on database test to developer;
```

This only grants view of the database and not the schema or any other objects within the database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately in Snowflake, there is no as such command to grant all access via a single command.

Even with all privileges command, you have to grant one usage privilege against the object to be effective.

It's mentioned in the [documentation on Schema Privileges](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#schema-privileges) as well.

For future grants, you can try following commands at schema and database level

SCHEMA LEVEL

```
grant usage on database SAMPLEDATABASE1 to role testrole12;
grant usage on schema SAMPLEDATABASE1.TEST to role testrole12;
grant select on future tables in schema SAMPLEDATABASE1.TEST to role testrole12;
grant role testrole12 to user SUJANT3;
```

DATABASE LEVEL

```
grant usage on database SAMPLEDATABASE1 to role testrole12;
grant usage on future schemas in database SAMPLEDATABASE1 to role testrole12;
grant select on future tables in database SAMPLEDATABASE1 to role testrole12;
grant role testrole12 to user SUJANT3;
```

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Please see the [help page on expected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) on chitchat.

Answer (score 3):

There is no one single command to affect all the objects under the database, but you can run these set of SQL's per object:

```
GRANT ALL ON ALL schemas in database <DB> TO ROLE <role>; 
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA <db.schema> TO ROLE <role>;
```

similarly for future grants:

```
grant all on future schemas in database <DB> TO ROLE <role>;

grant all on future tables in schema <db.schema> to ROLE <role>;
```

This can be extended to views and other objects too.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to grant [ownership](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-ownership.html)? There can only be 1 owner per object, so I recommend you use this only when appropriate:

```sql
GRANT OWNERSHIP ON DATABASE TEST
   TO DEVELOPER
   COPY CURRENT GRANTS
;
```

Note: Copying current grants retains the current privileges, except ownership is transferred. Otherwise, all existing privileges will be dropped.